# How to install allegro 5 for MinGW without using an ide?

Tags: c++, mingw, allegro5

I am trying to learn how to use allegro 5, but all of the tutorials I can find are using either code blocks or dev c++. I have compiled a program fine on windows without using a library using mingGw alone, how would I create and compile an allegro program without an ide?

Comment: https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Getting_Started

Answer (score 1):

You can configure MinGW or Cygwin to build allegro. This is a complete MinGW port of Allegro: 
http://liballeg.org/stabledocs/en/build/mingw32.html